# How to calculate deceleration of a rocket while descending?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion

Lets say i have a model rocket that is propelled by Liquid Rocket Engine.(**This speculation is according to my knowledge ......that could be wrong** ) The engine provides a thrust of 300N and has an apogee at 15000m above surface and is currently at apogee. Its mass is about 10 kg at launch but it has burnt 40 kg fuel and is now 60kg.So if i apply the formula Thrust of Rocket - Mass of rocket * 9.8/mass then it should provide an deceleration of (**Hypothetically no atmospheric deceleration**)

300 - 10 * 9.8/10 = 20.2

after falling for 35 seconds from apogee - it goes to 8.8 from 15 km of height

now , I light the engine to decelerate - I can bring the rocket to stop in next 17.5 seconds while reaching to the height of 6 KM *approximation*

The total fuel in the rocket is about 44 kgs and it has 90 % of its fuel till apogee and after apogee it has 40 seconds of fuel remaining

**So the Question is , is my speculation and *Simulation* correct?**

*Is this the correct way to do it?*

**If not then how is it done?**

**If its correct  how will the science work to hover the rocket?**

The reason i believe this question is worth asking is that it sounds little bit (**senseless**) to me saying that the rocket will also decelerate if I apply only 75 N on this rocket to slow it down (its senseless to me because it is decelerating slower that the acceleration by gravity that is 9.8m/s^2)

Comment: You need to specify the mass of the rocket after burning all of the fuel.  Note that the mass being accelerated (or hovered) changes as the fuel is being burned. Are you trying to get the rocket back to the ground with a zero velocity?

Comment: @R.W.Bird yes im doing something like that , my final aim is to understand that how do rocket physics work ;) , i will provide the numbers in the awnsere